# Element VAR is undefined in ATTRIBUTES ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am trying to call a method from a java class but I am getting an exception I haven't seen before.

This is what I get back when I am calling the class and one of the methods and how I got this

```
<cfdump var="#nlp#">
<cfdump var="#nlp.run()#">
```

[image]

And this is the exception I got when I am trying to dump the method

```
19:12:31.031 - Expression Exception - in Z:/Sites/xamplifier/views/surveyreporting/wordcloud.cfm : line 157
        Element VAR is undefined in ATTRIBUTES.
```

Am I calling the method in a wrong way? This is how we had the code on CF9 and everything works but CF 11 seems to have issues...

Comment: (Edit) If the error is from cfdump, it could just be because `run()` is returning `null`. That is not uncommon for java classes, so it is not necessarily a problem, unless you are saying the *exact same code* behaves differently in CF9. Ignoring the cfdump, what were you expecting to happen and what does `run()` return in CF9?

Comment: I'm with Leigh - cfdump is incredibly useful but it sometimes scratches it's head over various Java returns.

Comment: So basically the original code goes something like this `<cfset result = "#nlp.run()#">` and then we loop around the `result` to create our output on the screen... EDIT: the `result` is an array

Comment: Without knowing anything about the class, there is really no way to know why it is returning `null`. Not unless it is due to an error of some kind (check the exception logs to be sure). It is quite common for a java method to return `null` if some conditions are not met, but that is dictated by the code itself. So it is impossible to say exactly *why* that is happening here (and not under CF9) without knowing more about the class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Open_NPL `run()` method is generating an exception, which is caught and causes it to return `null`. See here: [Open_NPS Source](https://github.com/athosprv/Photoalbum/blob/master/open_NLP/Open_NLP.java#L88)

Agree with the other answers, you'll just have to test for NULL to avoid the CF exception, and dig into the Java to determine the root cause.

Comment: Good find of the source code. No idea why the code catches exceptions and prints them to stdout though, rather than letting them bubble up. Then at least the calling app would be aware there was a problem. @Geo - Check the various logs. Not sure where the message will end up, but it probably *won't* be in the standard exception log since the code is using `System.out.println`.

Comment: I know the guy who created the source but unfortunately he is unavailable the past few days. He is the same guy who worked on our CF9 version and also my former roommate :)

Answer (score 1):

The Java method is returning NULL, which in ColdFusion is the same as not being defined.  You need to capture the result and test it.

```
<cfset local = {}><!--- if inside a function, this isn't necessary --->
<cfset local.result = nlp.run() >
<cfif not isNull( local.result ) >
  <cfdump var="local.result">
<cfelse>
  NULL!
</cfif>
```

Comment: I understand the NULL part but why is it NULL though?